# Image float right when certain number pixels available

Tags: css

so I want to wrap some text around an image. This is fine, I can use float:right; on the image element.

But I want to only float right when there is more than 200px on the side. Is this possible.
E.g.

```
       _____
      |img |
      |    |
      |____|
Text here.....

             _____
Text here.  |img |
..          |    |
            |____|
```

Or do I need to do this in javascript?

Comment: By 200px on the side, do you mean extra space on the side of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `padding:left:200px` or `margin-left:200px`.

If not, there are many other ways to do this.